# How to resize image html besides width

Tags: html, image

This may come off as basic, but I'm new to img tags. On this website [morningsignout.com](http://morningsignout.com/new-insight-into-treating-traumatic-brain-injuries-part-i/), I want to resize the images so that they're smaller. I learned about editing their img tag properties in firebug with "height="40%"", but it doesn't seem to work on any of the article's main images. How do I resize them in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming that you want to resize the image according to the height of the view window. To do that, you can use the vh unit in css. 100 vh units is the height of the screen that the user is viewing the page on.

Here's an example that sets all the imgs to 40% of the viewport height

```css
img {
  height: 40vh;
}
```

Comment: Where do I insert that?

Comment: That goes into either your .css file or inside <style> tags in your html document

Comment: I hope I can do this through html. How do I insert this inside style?

Comment: Something like this:
` <style>
//code goes here
</style>`

Comment: Does <img style="height:40vh"> work? Or does the style tag go somewhere else in the html doc?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Otherwise you could use the style tags that I showed above in the head of your html document

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

Height with percents it's a little bit tricky because the parent must have `height` too. You have 2 options: Set the parent's height too. B. Set the height by pixels.

```css
.first {
  height: 450px;
}

.first img {
  height:50%;
}

.second img {
  height:200px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/33oYG.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="second">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/33oYG.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Where do the class declarations go in the html?

Comment: The `img` tag inside the `div` with the class `first` or `second`